# Cannot GET node js error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't figure out where I missed to add something. I get the following error: `Cannot GET /portal/destroybox/5797318673cf3f581163455c` when I click on delete or update icons in `portal.ejs`:

(`createbox` in `portal.ejs` works and creates the item and stores it in the db, and then I `forEach` in the table to show all items with update and delete icons behind each item. Also the `// todo test` part in server.js is for another part of my app and that works, nothing to do with the portal/box part. I also do not have route in `server.js` for createbox, but that part works, so why do I need it for destroybox if I need it at all?)

`portal.ejs`

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Vm</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% boxes.forEach( function ( box ){ %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= box.box_name %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= box.vm %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true" href="/portal/editbox/<%= box._id %>" title="Update this box"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" href="/portal/destroybox/<%= box._id %>" title="Destroy this box"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>
    <strong>Add new box to `available boxes`</strong>
    <br>
</p>

<form action="/createbox" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Box name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="box_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>VM</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vm">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add box</button>
</form>
```

`server.js`

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need

// mongoose setup
var db = require('./config/database.js');

require('./app/models/db');
require('./app/models/box');

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var logger = require('morgan');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var static = require('serve-static');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');

var routesindex = require('./routes/index');
//var routesbox = require('./routes/boxi');


// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(db.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.use(logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secretkeykeykeykey'
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes ======================================================================
var routes = require('./app/routes/routes')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// todo test
app.use(routesindex.current_user);
app.get('/ind', routesindex.ind); 
app.post('/ind/create', routesindex.create);
app.get('/ind/destroy/:id', routesindex.destroy);
app.get('/ind/edit/:id', routesindex.edit);
app.post('/ind/update/:id', routesindex.update);

app.use(static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

`routes.js`

```
// =====================================
    // PORTAL ==============================
    // =====================================
    // show the signup form
    app.get('/portal', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        var user_id = req.cookies ?
            req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

        Box.
        find({
            user_id: user_id
        }).
        sort('-updated_at').
        exec(function (err, boxes) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            res.render('portal', {
                boxes: boxes
            });
        });
    });

    app.post('/createbox', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        new Box({
            user_id: req.cookies.user_id,
            box_name: req.body.box_name,
            vm: req.body.vm,
            description: req.body.description,
            updated_at: Date.now()
        }).save(function (err, box, count) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            res.redirect('/portal/');
        });
    });

    app.get('/destroybox/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        Box.findById(req.params.id, function (err, box) {
            var user_id = req.cookies ?
                req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

            if (box.user_id !== user_id) {
                return utils.forbidden(res);
            }

            box.remove(function (err, box) {
                if (err) return next(err);

                res.redirect('/portal/');
            });
        });
    });

    app.get('/editbox/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        var user_id = req.cookies ?
            req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

        Box.
        find({
            user_id: user_id
        }).
        sort('-updated_at').
        exec(function (err, boxes) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            res.render('editbox', {
                title: 'Vagrant Box',
                boxes: boxes,
                current: req.params.id
            });
        });
    });

    app.post('/updatebox/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        Box.findById(req.params.id, function (err, box) {
            var user_id = req.cookies ?
                req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

            if (box.user_id !== user_id) {
                return utils.forbidden(res);
            }

            box.box_name = req.body.box_name;
            box.vm = req.body.vm;
            box.description = req.body.description;
            box.updated_at = Date.now();
            box.save(function (err, box, count) {
                if (err) return next(err);

                res.redirect('/portal/');
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, solution given by Jai works. Hehe, wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have routes for that as the error states:

```
app.get('/destroybox/:id'
```

You can see you have a route from **root** `/` to **destroybox** then **:id** etc. While you are having a href of:

```
 href="/portal/destroybox/<%= box._id %>"
```

from **root** `/` to **portal** and then **destroybox** then the **id**. Which is no where defined in the config.

---

Solution is to change the href to:

```
href="/destroybox/<%= box._id %>"
```

same goes for other href attributes too.

Comment: big bloated question, nice concise answer :).

Comment: Hehe, I think I tried that before, but did not work. It works now hehe thanks for the solution. Will mark as solution, need to wait 4 minutes tho.